# Macvim color scheme conflicting with .vimrc

Tags: vim, macvim

In my `.vimrc`, I specify that when I do a search, I want the terms to be highlighted - background color yellow, foreground black. Here's how I specify that:

```
" Settings for terminal version of vim
:highlight Search ctermbg=yellow ctermfg=black
" Settings for gvim (linux) / macvim
:highlight Search guibg=yellow guifg=black
```

I'm also using a nice color scheme (railscasts) in Macvim. It seems to override my highlighting colors, however, to something barely visible. If I reload my `.vimrc`, all is well again.

Is there a way to cause my `.vimrc` settings to win in any conflicts with the color scheme? If not, would it be better to modify the color scheme itself? Write a little script that causes vim to automatically reload the `.vimrc` after the color scheme loads? What's the best approach here?

Comment: Have you tried moving this to .gvimrc ?  I believe that will be processed after .vimrc.

Comment: @Jack M. - that indeed was the problem. If you care to make your comment into an answer, I will accept it. :) Thank you!

Comment: **Update** - I am now using the Solarized color scheme, which is very easy to read and, among other things, sets a good highlighting color for me, so I don't have to do the above at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to move these colours into `.gvimrc` instead of `.vimrc`.  `.gvimrc` is processed later as it is intended to override settings and be specific for GVim.

Answer (score 0):

Order is important.  Are you running these :highlight commands before or after your :colorscheme command?  If it's before, try changing the order.

However, there are reasons this still may not work.  If this is the case, you can try putting your :highlight commands in ~/.vim/after/syntax/syncolor.vim (I'm not sure what the MacOS equivalent of this path would be), which is automatically loaded on various events.